# Adjustable current source in range of pA

Tags: circuit-design, ltspice, current-source

I have an assignment to develop and draw a circuit current source that delivers an adjustable currents in the pA range on LTspice for a school project and I need help with it.

I've tried using an op-amp or a N-MOSFET, but I keep connecting it wrong.

I am still a beginner, so I think I connected it somewhat wrong, I would welcome any feedback.

Here's my attempt.

I used an op-amp, sweep from 0 to 9 pV, which I feel like might not have been the practical approach, but that's all what I could come up with

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please post a schematic of your attempt.

Comment: What does the pA need to source or sink into? As it's currently drawn, the opamp output goes nowhere so no current can flow.

Comment: That's a tough one. Does this need to work in reality, or just in simulation?

Comment: @winny The assignment doesn't clarify, it just states that i need to develop a current source with an adjustable pA output

Comment: @Hearth it does need to work in reality, because I have to build it afterwards to test it out. if there's a more practical way to build it, please let me know.

Comment: Anything to do with picoamps is inherently impractical. There are a *lot* of considerations to keep out leakage from external sources. What's your budget for this? Expect building this in reality to cost several thousand dollars.

Comment: Lol really? cause the professor is expecting me to do it on a Breadboard. Just a simple circuit, nothing fancy. but with an output of pA that is adjustable. @Hearth

Comment: Are you sure we're talking about picoamps here? that's orders of magnitude lower than you can expect any degree of precision out of something built on a breadboard. Picoamps requires specialized PCB design techniques, triaxial cables, and extremely high-impedance amplifiers. This isn't a task I would expect someone to ask a student to do. Unless they're trying to get you to realize the difficulties on your own, perhaps?

Comment: I just rechecked the assignment the professor wrote, to develop a current source that delivers adjustable currents in the pA range
@Hearth

Comment: if you have  any idea for the simulation, that would be enough for now, so that i can submit it at least. @Hearth

Comment: @MohammedJacob In simulation, everything's perfect, so you can just use a Howland current source with an ideal op amp and be done with it.

Comment: If no requirement on output, short it to ground, put a 1 Gohm resistor and use precision mV voltage source. The leakage currents will make it near impossible on a breadboard and thermal EMFs of dissimilar materials will come into play too.

Comment: What kind of class is this for? Is it for an IC design class? I think that context is quite important.

Comment: The class is called applied Electronics, but the professor want me to have it as a project so i can use it for a thesis later on as well. so once I got the design, I can go ahead and start my project for my thesis early on. @Ste Kulov

Comment: OK, so it doesn't sound like an IC class.  Here's one idea (you didn't specify if it needs to be a current source or sink or both).  It's a PNP current mirror controlled by a voltage source which can **sink** current.  It's only linear in the 9V to 10V range.  You can purchase matched transistor pairs such as the [DMMT3906W](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/DMMT3906W-7-F/717760).  [Click here for an image of the circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALIuA.png)